# how to split dataframe if column value change value python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

i want to split dataframe when value of `flag` column change to `1`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,20,40,45,56,1,20,40,45,56],'flag':[3,2,4,1,1,3,3,1,1,1]})

Out[63]: 
    A  flag
0   1     3
1  20     2
2  40     4
3  45     1
4  56     1
5   1     3
6  20     3
7  40     1
8  45     1
9  56     1

desired out:

print(group_1)
    A  flag
0   1     3
1  20     2
2  40     4

print(group_2)
    A  flag
0   1     3
1  20     3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on the [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)ed DataFrame, with groups starting on each 1:

```
mask = df['flag'].eq(1)
groups = [g for _,g in df[~mask].groupby(mask.cumsum())]
```

output:

```
groups[0]

    A  flag
0   1     3
1  20     2
2  40     4

groups[1]

    A  flag
5   1     3
6  20     3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = list()
flag = True
start = 0
for index,value in df['flag'].items():
    if value==1 and index-1>0 and flag:
        flag = False
        result.append(df.iloc[start:index,])
    elif value!=1 and not flag:
        start = index
        flag = True
```

[image: result]